# Fabio grpc route not found even though service properly registered

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, grpc, consul, fabio

I am trying to figure out why my fabio service does not reroute properly.

The closest thing that I found close to my issue is this github issue -> https://github.com/fabiolb/fabio/issues/605

Here is my routing table properly registered
[image: fabio]

- Service: event-grpc-service
- Source: /event-grpc-service
- Dest: grpc://event.grpc:81
- Options: strip=/event-grpc-service

> The grpc only has one method you can view more details below. I tried calling

- localhost:9999/event-grpc-service <-  This one should be a route registered in fabio
- localhost:9999/event-grpc-service/Event
- localhost:9999/event-grpc-service/Event/GetEvent

All Print the following logs in fabio.

```
2023/03/19 19:39:45 [WARN] No route for *
```

[image: postman]

**Could someone please help me fix it?**

Below some more information regarding how it is all set up.

```
  consul:
    image: consul
    container_name: consul
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - odin
    ports:
      - 8500:8500
    volumes:
      - consul:/consul/data
  
  fabio:
    image: fabiolb/fabio
    container_name: fabio
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - FABIO_REGISTRY_CONSUL_ADDR=consul:8500
    networks:
      - odin
    ports:
      - 9998:9998
      - 9999:9999
```

Here is also the proto file:
An out of the box template will do the trick. Just for reference

```
syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "Event.Grpc";

import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";


package event.protos;

service Event {
  rpc GetEvent (GetEventRequest) returns (EventResponse);
}

message GetEventRequest {
  int64 id = 1;
}

message EventResponse {
  int64 id = 1;
  string name = 2;
  google.protobuf.Timestamp starting = 3;
  string category = 4;
  repeated Market markets = 5;
}

message Market {
  string name = 1;
  StakeLimits stake_limits = 2;
  repeated Selection selections = 3;
}

message StakeLimits
{
  DecimalValue minStake = 1;
  DecimalValue maxStake = 2;
}

message Selection {
  string name = 1;
  DecimalValue price = 2;
}

message DecimalValue {
  // Whole units part of the amount
  int64 units = 1;

  //Nano units of the amount (10^-9)
  //Must be the same sign as units
  sfixed32 nanos = 2;
}
```